# Polymorphism and overloaded operators

Tags: c++

I am playing around with operator overloading in my inherited class. It works fine when I define the overloaded operator in a single class (`+` in the example below). However, I cannot make it work with polymorphism (`[]`) - I get the error messages

```
main.cpp:70:36: error: ‘int A::operator[]() const’ must take exactly one argument
   virtual int operator[]() const = 0;
                                    ^
main.cpp:80:28: error: ‘int B::operator[]() const’ must take exactly one argument
   virtual int operator[]() const { return b; }
                            ^~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:90:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
   std::cout << (*a_ptr)[] << "\n";
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A(){};
  virtual ~A(){};
  virtual int operator[]() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
  int b;

public:
  B(int b_) : b(b_){};
  virtual int operator[]() const { return b; }
  int operator+(const B &rhs) const { return b + rhs.b; }
  int get() { return b; }
};

int main()
{

  ///this gives an error: 
  A *a_ptr = new B(100);
  std::cout << (*a_ptr)[] << "\n";  

  ///this works fine
  B a(10), b(100);
  std::cout << a.get() << "\n";
  std::cout << b.get() << "\n";
  b = a + b;
  std::cout << b.get() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Is the `[]`-operator special since it must take exactly one argument?

Comment: The problem have nothing to do with polymorphism. You did *read* the error message? What does it say? And how would you use the "*index* operator" without providing an index? You can't change the syntax of the language with operator overloading. Perhaps you should think about overloading the function call operator (`operator()`) instead?

Comment: I am a bit confused. You are doing it right with the operator+ - you give it one argument, as it should. Why don't you do the same thing with the operator [], which also needs one argument for the index - there has to be something in between the [] ;)

Comment: @user2328447 Actually the `operator+` function is not *really* correctly implemented. It should return `B` by value. It's not invalid to change the semantics of operators, but it's highly recommended *not* to do that. For example, right now it's not possible to do e.g. `some_b_object + another_b_object + a_third_b_object`.

Comment: Yeah, come on: _"I get the error message"_ So what? Is that error not completely clear and accurate? Or do you disagree, and why do you think you know better than the compiler/language how an operator should work?

Comment: To the OP, about the `operator+` overloading, I recommend you take some time to [read this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), especially [this section about overloading binary arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, I'll take a look at it. Sorry for the vague question, I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Your'e right... I just looked at the argument and missed the result.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) explanation, the array subscript operator must have an argument, which is also indicated by the error message; apparently different signatures are not possible for the array subsript operator.